# Tkinter destroy method crashes the program

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a kind of GUI with tkinter, and here is the code. But, when I run it, click settings, and then back, python crashes. Do you have any idea why this might happen and how I would fix it? It happens when either I run the destroy function, or when I do something in the other Tk window,

The code: (some might not be necessary, but I will include it)

```
import tkinter as tk

class moveFrame():
    def move(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.place(x = widget.winfo_x() + event.x - widget.startX, y = widget.winfo_y() + event.y - widget.startY)

def resize(self, event):
    widget = event.widget
    wlength = widget["length"]
    wwidth = widget["width"]
    widget.config(length = wlength + event.x - widget.startX, width = wwidth + event.y - widget.startY)

def getPos(self, event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.lift()
    widget.startX, widget.startY = event.x, event.y

def __init__(self, master, frameInfo, xPos, yPos):
    self.frame = tk.Frame(master, cnf = frameInfo)
    self.frame.bind("<Button-1>", self.getPos)
    self.frame.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move)
    self.frame.bind("<B3-Motion>", self.getPos)
    self.frame.bind("<Button-3>", self.resize)
    self.frame.place(x = xPos, y = yPos)


def homescreen():
    screen = tk.Tk()
    #arrangeButton = tk.Canvas(screen, width = 120, height = 40, bg = "purple")
    #arrangeButton.create_text(60, 20, text = "Arrange Homescreen")
    #arrangeButton.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    #arrangeButton.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: arrange(arrangeButton))
    settingsButton = tk.Canvas(screen, width = 60, height = 60)
    settingsButton.place(x = 20, y = 20)
    settingsButton.create_oval(5, 5, 58, 58, fill = "#a6a6a6", tags = "click")
    settingsButton.create_oval(15, 10, 58, 53, fill = "#000", tags = "click")
    settingsButton.create_oval(27, 22, 46, 41, fill = "#00f", tags = "click")
    settingsButton.tag_bind("click", "<Button-1>", lambda event: settings())

def settings():
    sscreen = tk.Tk()
    #Get previous settings
    try:
        file = open("settings.txt", "r")
    except IOError:
        file = open("settings.txt", "x")
    finally:
        file = open("settings.txt", "r+")
    curSet = [x.strip("\n") for x in file.readlines()]
    #Widgets
    back = tk.Canvas(sscreen, width = 60, height = 48)
    back.place(x = 20, y = 20)
    back.create_rectangle(25, 22, 60, 26, fill = "#000", tags = "sclick")
    back.create_polygon(10, 24, 25, 10, 25, 38, fill = "#000", tags = "sclick")
    back.create_text(42, 32, text = "Back", tags = "sclick")
    back.tag_bind("sclick", "<Button-1>", lambda event: sscreen.destroy())

def arrange(*widgets):
    arrangeScreen = tk.Tk()
    arrangeButton = widgets[0]
    aBaF = moveFrame(arrangeScreen, {"bd" : 4, "bg" : "#a6a6a6"}, arrangeButton.winfo_x() - 4, arrangeButton.winfo_y() - 4)
    aBa = tk.Canvas(aBaF, width = 120, height = 40, bg = "purple")


def load(goTo, ms):
    load = tk.Tk()
    loadImage = tk.Canvas(load, height = 300, width = 300, bg = "black")
    loadImage.pack()
    loadImage.create_oval(125, 130, 175, 180, fill = "white")
    loadImage.create_oval(130, 140, 170, 150, fill = "black")
    loadImage.create_oval(130, 140, 171, 151, fill = "white")
    loadImage.create_oval(152, 140, 148, 150, fill = "black")
    load.after(ms, lambda: [goTo(), load.destroy()])

load(homescreen, 1)
```

Comment: A minimal example and a trace back would go a long way.

Comment: Do you run this script within IDLE ?

Comment: What does "python crashes" mean? Do you get a stack trace? Also, the indentation in your code sample is broken.

Comment: You aren't calling `mainloop`, and you're creating more than once instance of `Tk`. Both of those are red flags. A tkinter program is designed to have exactly one instance of `Tk`, and to call `mainloop` exactly once.

Comment: @BryanOakley 1: Pyhton crashes means windows says: "Python has stopped working, and it closes the tkinter window" 

2: Thanks for the thing about the Tk, but I run a bunch of my programs without running mainloop(), and it runs fine, and also, It does create the second Tk window, but when I try to destroy it, it crashes

Comment: @BryanOakley so should I put a screen.destroy() in the lambda to go to the settings. But if I do, it still crashes, even though there is only on tk screen open, it still crashes

Comment: Ideally you would have one root window that is seperate from the other windows (and hidden) and all the windows that are coming and going are all `TopLevel` widgets instead of `Tk` apps.

Comment: How are you running this script? `mainloop` must run, so either you're running it, or you're using some sort of tool that runs it for you. What tool is that?

Comment: @MrYurihiredstone without calling `mainloop` the program will only ever run in an IDE that keeps an interactive shell after the program finishes (like IDLE), trying to run it in a regular python interpreter it doesn't run at all (hence above comment)

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thats the thing! The python window crashes, and windows closes it

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks! Didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program represents one application, only make one `Tk` instance.

The `Tk` object represents the root of the entire application, by deleting it and creating another one you are essentially creating a separate application and any references to the previously application results in undefined behaviour such as crashing python.

Instead of using `Tk` as separate windows use `Toplevel` as that is what they are intended for, separate windows.

By replacing all occurences of `tk.Tk()` in your program with `tk.Toplevel(abs_root)` then defining `abs_root` as `tk.Tk()` like this:

```
abs_root = tk.Tk()
abs_root.withdraw() #hides the window while your program runs.
load(homescreen, 1)
abs_root.mainloop()
```

Will make your program work, however it does mean that it will run until `abs_root` is destroyed which cannot happen by clicking the close button since it is not shown as a window, you will either have to use some condition where you explicitly call `abs_root.destroy()` or choose one window that will be the first created and last to be closed and use that as the `abs_root` instead.  (not possible with your program as it is written)